# How to query your data in mongoDB compass with case insensitive option?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I am trying to query data in MongoDB compass GUI based on multiple values using `$in`.

My query is this -

```
{category : {[$in: ['a012','b23c','5870T']}}
```

I want to query these values with case insensitive option `i`. The operator `$in` also doesn't accept regex expressions as per documentation.

What would be the correct query with the case insensitive option included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.mycollection.find({'category':{$in:[/a012/i, /b23c/i, /5870T/i]}})
```

A couple of ways to do this:

1. To limit to the 'word boundaries' of the string, you can use `\b`

```js
db.mycollection.find({'category':{$in:[/\ba012\b/i, /\bb23c\b/i, /\b5870T\b/i]}})
```

2. Use the `m` option to match the beginning and end of the string

```js
db.mycollection.find({'category':{$in:[/a012/im, /b23c/im, /5870T/im]}})
```

Comment: Thanks..but the query is not returning the exact string content provided for example it also returns 'aab23caa' instead of just 'b23c'. Like it is querying somewhat like this (any character)b23c(any character). Is there any way to query the exact same string with just case insensitive ?..like it should return 'b2c3', 'B2C3' etc..

Comment: I've edited my answer to better answer your specific question.